# How to overwrite a css style from another css file?

Tags: css

I need to overwrite the header style from style.css.

Here's the style that I need to overwrite.

```
.t_header{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #bfd4f0;  
    color:#15428b;
    white-space:nowrap ;
    margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;
    height:1.5em;
}
```

Now I created another css file name black.css and I need to create a different background color for `.t_header`

```
.t_header{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white !important; 
    color:#15428b;
    white-space:nowrap ;
    margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;
    height:1.5em;
}
```

I already used `!important` to overwrite the style from style.css but its not working but for some reason, the other style class and id that I overwrite using !important worked well. 
I hope someone can give me another way to overwrite the style aside using `!important`. Thanks

Comment: Did you try loading the desired CSS after the old CSS is loaded?

Comment: Open the page in Chrome, right click > inspect element on the header, in the bottom right pane, click computed tab, expand the background-color property and post a screenshot.

Comment: If `!important` is not working for you *(it should work)* can first try more specific selector, still it fails, than you are left with document level style or inline style

Comment: @SalmanA I would prefer Firebug + Firefox screenshot

Comment: yes. I'm creating a theme. Where when you chose the theme black, all colors will change and when you choose blue,the color blue will be seen.. style.css is the default css file where if you choose blue and the style of the header is not available, thats when style.css style can be use.

Comment: @Mr.Alien: haven't used FireBug for quite some time; the Chrome tip will easily point you to the styles that are applied (or cancelled out) along with file name and line number. Does not get better than this.

Comment: @Mr.Alien thanks, but i can't really use it like that, I have a file name contol.aspx and you will have to call the css file theme there, if you call black.css, black theme will be used, but if you call green.css, it will overwrite black and everything will turn green

Comment: @Lyn than don't override, remove black, and use only green

Comment: @Mr.Alien I have a default css style that all themes overwrite and its purpose is to be implemented if ever the style of such field is not available on the selected style. im creating black and im trying to overwrite the default style but its not working when thats what i did on all other style

Comment: @Lyn it is better you clone the stylesheets, overriding will be an headache here

Comment: @Mr.Alien no other way aside using !important :( all i need to do is to overwrite t_header and its all done :(

Comment: @Lyn are you changing the backgrounds only? It is better to swipe out the stylehseets you don't use... else `!important` and `!important` will get redundant, and that's where the stylesheet order will play the role

Comment: @Mr.Alien mostly all dialog boxes and all borders is what im changing so basically, all themes will change :(

Comment: @Lyn clone the stylesheets, swap the stylesheets, get rid of the old stylesheet from the DOM, is the best I can suggest

Comment: @Mr.Alien I can't, I can't change anything from the default style even from other style so the only solution is to overwrite it when theme black is selected >.<

Comment: @Lyn than you will just bang your head like [this](http://oi45.tinypic.com/alqcyo.jpg)

Comment: I'am since yesterday lol >.< im so pass my deadline

Comment: The code posted does not reproduce the problem. Using `!important` is almost always wrong approach, but technically it works for the given issue. The question is off-topic unless augmented by a complete example (HTML + CSS) that actually demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try to clear your browser cache, then add the files in your code in the following sequence -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="black.css">
```

The overriding css doesn't need to have all properties -

This much code will be enough -

```
.t_header{
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Sequence does matter, but he is using `!important` and that doesn't affect is what I doubt, may be inheritance plays role there

Comment: Clearing the browser cache! I always forget how important that is.

Answer (score 0):

Using `!IMPORTANT` is generally not recommended. Try increasing specificity

```
body div.theader { background: white; }
```

Also keep in mind that it's generally frowned upon to use more than four selectors.

you get the idea...

Comment: thanks, but i can't really use it like that, I have a file name contol.aspx and you will have to call the css file theme there, if you call black.css, black theme will be used, but if you call green.css, it will overwrite black and everything will turn green